# Find OnKeyPress JavaScript in Chrome Inspector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have the following HTML code that doesn't have `OnKeyPress`, `OnKeyUp`, `OnKeyDown` property hence JavaScript is handling the HTML element, in the site https://dev.ther8server.com (Please excuse the self signed SSL) how can I find which property is managing the operations of autocomplete function for the textbox `keywords` and how to find which property is responsible for this operation in Chrome Ispector?

HTML code

```
<input type="text" id="keywords" onfocus="this.value='';" value="Brisbane, Queensland, Australia" name="keywords" brisbane,="" queensland,="" australia="" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

Sorry can't attached JavaScript cause I am not sure which JavaScript is responsible and site is calling many external JavaScript files.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: If i understand your question (property???), use in console: `$._data($('#keywords')[0],'events')` Returns all **events** bound to element with jquery

Comment: Can I ask for my knowledge, what is this >> brisbane,="" queensland,="" australia="" ... Sorry for disturbing.

Comment: @AhmedHamdy- City, State, Country. Don't know why its trying to pass in special parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its in https://dev.ther8server.com/assets/js/main.js

Search for: $("input#keywords").bind("keydown",function(e)